What did he say or What has he said?
Imagine, you are sitting on a lecture with your friend. The lector just said something you didn't recognise or didn't understand. You want to ask the question to you friend. How to do it correctly?

What did he say?
What has he said?


This question is similar to: Present-perfect-tense vs. Simple-past-tense. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To summarize the info at the duplicate: Present perfect is for talking about how the past action affects the present. I can't imagine a realistic reason to use it in this scenario.

Suppose that you asked person A to ask person B about something. Next time you see person A, you would ask person A:

What did he say?

If you are with person A and person B, and you didn't hear what person B said a moment ago, you would ask person A:

What did he just say?

If you suspect that person A is upset because of something that person B said, you might ask person A

What did he say [to upset you]?
What has he said [to upset you]?


very good explanation.
